# How to autoplay ogg stream at startup of Debian

Tags: audio, raspbian, ogg

I am programming a Rasberry to Pi to become a radio player.
It is meant to be used to play the [local college radio](http://radiocampus.se/) in the student union hangout.

INPUT:

- Power is turn on.

OUTPUT:

- Audio is played through the 3,5 mm jack.

PROCESS:

1. Device boot Raspdebian
2. ...
3. Start playing an ogg stream (/radiocampus_local.m3u)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a script in `/etc/init.d`, for instance "read_radio".

You have to set the proper rights on it `chmod +x /etc/init.d/read_radio`

You have to edit the file and create the script that will launch the radio, for instance:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/mplayer -shuffle -playlist /path/to/radiocampus_local.m3u
```

Or whatever method you want to use to read your m3u file

Comment: +1 for the `mplayer -playlist`, which I didn’t know and hence have written my own script to read playlists and play them with mplayer. Wasted time …

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mechanism to have something start on boot-up. I don't know where the audio comes from that is specified in the `.m3u` file, but certainly if it is from a network, you should make sure everything the playback needs is operational.

A simple solution might be to put the command in `/etc/rc.local` as a background task.

The other thing you could look at is making an entry in `/etc/init.d`. And make a link in `/etc/rc2.d` (adduming 2 is the normal runlevel for a Raspberry Pi, check with `runlevel`), to that file. The name should be `SXY...` with XY a chosen number so that this is started (`S`) after all the dependent services are up and running.

What is less likely to work is making a `@reboot` entry in a crontab (assuming you have Vixie cron), not all prerequisites might be met by the time that runs.